# PHP with Python

Tags: php, python

This is my Python Code :

```
import threading
import time
import MySQLdb
import sys

conn=MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
        user = "root",
        passwd = "",
        db = "profiles_sheduleit")
cur = conn.cursor()

def activation():       
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print time.time()

t = threading.Thread(name='activation', target=activation)
t.start()
```

I am calling this page from my php page 
by:

```
$result = exec("c:/python27/python f:/python/hello.py");
```

I have one few buttons in php when this button is clicked a new thread should me created and that thread should run for 10 seconds.

but when i click the button m not able to click another button because python script goes into sleep mode thanx

Comment: activation function, has an infinite loop

Answer (score 3):

your python script never terminates because your thread runs for ever due to your `while True:` statement. This causes the `exec` function to wait indefinitely. All PHP's exec like functions are blocking, meaning that they'll wait until the process they call has returned.

Look into something like [gearman](http://gearman.org/), if you want to create a work queue. It's essentially a job server that allows for async execution.